# Object Property Renaming

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a question regarding why the following returns inconsistent values

```
(function(ab, $, undefined ) {

    ​ab.cool = {
        nice: {
            funky: {
                sweet: false
            }    
        }
    };

    var reVal = ab.cool.nice.funky.sweet;
    reVal = true;

    console.log(reVal); //equals true
    console.log(ab.cool.nice.funky.sweet); //equals false

}( window.ab = window.ab || {}, jQuery ));​
```

I would have thought that both SHOULD return the same value `true` ?

Can someone please explain why this occurs ? Are they considered different properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the value of `ab.cool.nice.funky.sweet` gets copied to `reVal`. This would not happen if you tried to copy `ab.cool.nice.funky` to `reVal`, since both symbols would then reference the same object.

This differentiation is the product of treating value types, such as booleans or integers, differently than reference types which in javascript basically means objects.

Check this for more info: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Comment: thanks for the explaination. so it's better practice to use `var reVal = ab.cool.nice.funky;` and then use `reVal.sweet = false;` ?

Comment: If you want to be able to control the same value from both symbols, yes, that's a solution.

Comment: The best practice, broadly speaking is to minimize references to the same object to avoid confusion and increase readability. So if you do have one reference to the object, you shouldn't create another unless you absolutely need it. If you need to have access to the value outside the closure, expose it above the closure, don't copy its reference.

Answer (score 3):

You don't rename the variable, you assign the value to another.

it's like:

```
$foo = $bar = true;
$bar = false;

print $foo; // true
print $bar; // false
```

Comment: get it :) brainfart - sorry for the stink but thanks for the help.